# How can I set the width of something in jquery based on variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a grid where the user can input a number, and then I create a grid based off that (i.e - user inputs 5, I create a 5x5 board).

All of my code has worked up until the point where I tried changing the height/width of the divs. What I'm trying to do now is change the CSS of each grid (made from a div) so that its height and width is dependent upon the number of divs created (I want a 5x5 board to take up the same space as a 10x10).

I set the # of divs to be created based off an input. I then run a loop creating the divs based off of (input * input). This all worked. My code stops working when I try and do this, though:

```
$(".indivCell").css("width", function() {
    return (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%");
});
$(".indivCell").css("height", function() {
    return (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%");
});
```

What I'm trying to do with that code is change the CSS-defined height and width based off of the input 'cellCount'. So, if someone puts in an answer of 5 to the cellCount prompt, I want the width to become ((5 / (5*5)*100)%. I've been googling this extensively and someone suggested this function/return route. Previously, I was trying this:

```
$(".indivCell").css("width", (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%")
$(".indivCell").css("height", (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%")
```

Which I'm now seeing doesn't work, either. This is the entire code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cellCount = prompt("Choose a number between 4 and 12 determine the size of your game board!");
if (cellCount > 3 && cellCount < 13) {
$(".indivCell").css("width", function() {
    return (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%");
});
$(".indivCell").css("height", function() {
    return (((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%");
});
for (var i = 0; i < (cellCount * cellCount); i += 1) {

$(".wrapper").append("<div class='indivCell'></div>");
};
} else {
alert("Welp, you failed to follow pretty basic instruction. Now you're getting a small board!");
var cellCount = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < (cellCount * cellCount); i += 1) {
$(".wrapper").append("<div class='indivCell'></div>");
};
}
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".indivCell").hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
});
```

My question is essentially, how do I call upon a variable that is defined to use that number in setting my jquery .css command?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: `(((cellCount / (cellCount * cellCount))*100) + "%") => (100/cellCount) + '%'`

Comment: @dfsq If it didn't work with the original code, why should optimization fix it? Perhaps you should take a dose of your own medicine, before dishing it out to others - we wrote virtually the exact same thing.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: @dfsq I simply copied the comment you wrote on my answer. I can't help you understand things you wrote yourself. You attempted to shoot me down because I wrote an optimisation, which is ironic because you also wrote an optimisation. In other words, if you're going to tell people that writing optimisations is useless, don't write optimisations yourself.

Comment: @ChristianVarga *"You attempted to shoot me down"*. No, I just pointed that your original answer was not going to work. At the same time my comment to the question was just a note for OP on improvement, but it didn't attempt to answer the question. Hence your reaction is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've massively overcomplicated things (don't worry, it happens!). The width in percentage is simply 100 / number of cells. For example, if you had 5 cells, 100 / 5 = 20% So something like this should work:

```
var cellSize = 100 / cellCount;
$(".indivCell").width(cellSize + '%');
```

One other problem is that you're adding the `.indivCell` items *after* you've attempted to set the size. This won't work; your call to .width() will only apply to elements that exist at the time of execution. So you need to add the items to the DOM first, then set their size.

```
for (var i = 0; i < (cellCount * cellCount); i += 1) {
    $(".wrapper").append("<div class='indivCell'></div>");
});

var cellSize = 100 / cellCount;
$(".indivCell").width(cellSize + '%');
```

Finally, height as a % doesn't work as you expect if the elements aren't positioned absolutely (that's another topic which I'm sure you can find out on some other SO answers). One way around it is to avoid using %s, and use pixel widths based on the parent container instead.

```
var cellSize = $('.wrapper').width() / cellCount;
$(".indivCell").width(cellSize).height(cellSize);
```

If the parent isn't exactly square, you can also set the width/height independently.

```
var cellWidth = $('.wrapper').width() / cellCount;
var cellHeight = $('.wrapper').height() / cellCount;
$(".indivCell").width(cellWidth).height(cellHeight);
```

Comment: If it didn't work with the original code, why should optimization fix it. This is the same.

Comment: Yeah, that was stupid of me, I've been to focused on why the code isn't running to realize it's a lot easier to type it out that way.

Still, the code doesn't work, even writing is better the way you have it. Am I able to reference a var like that when setting the height/width?

Comment: @JeremyH You'll probably need to post your CSS as well. How are the items positioned? If they're floated, setting height as a % won't work (your safest bet is to use pixel values instead)

Comment: @JeremyH I've updated my answer with a few more points that might help you out too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, man. I got it mostly working with your help. Still don't understand this damn height thing, but I've moved on. From what I'm seeing after a lot of googling, it doesn't appear I can just make the height one static size and expect all of the divs to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your making an interesting game... Memory ?
I did something similar a while ago, but don't have the code on me.

Your for loop should be something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cellCount * cellCount; i++) {
   $('<div/>', {
       id: 'cell' + i,
       class: 'indivCell',
       //add what ever other attributes you want, this will help 
       //later on when you trying to access each div inside the grid
   }).appendTo('.wrapper');
}
```

then make sure outside the for loop (for performance):

```
    var cellSize = (100 / cellCount) / 2;
    $(".indivCell").width(cellSize + '%');
    $(".indivCell").height(cellSize + '%');
```

here is the css:

```
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .indivCell {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #F00;
        display:inline-block;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid #FFF;
        padding:0;
    }
```

This will give you a visual output (probably close to what you want), you can then start altering CSS etc. accordingly to meet your specific needs.